# How do I make my iOS devices use British/Australian/Commonwealth spelling?

Tags: ios, spelling

I have the keyboard set to "British" and my locale is Australia, but neither of these seem to affect the spelling suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spelling is determined by the keyboard setting you're using. Go to Settings > General > International > Keyboards, and make sure that English (UK) is added. It also helps to remove the US keyboard so that you don't accidentally get stuck in that.

Comment: THANK you! Now I realise it was the "hardware" keyboard I had set to British, and it was an English (UK) software keyboard I had to add.

Comment: Glad to help. It seems obvious when you know, but it isn't the most intuitive thing.

Comment: It’s totally not obvious. I was certain that localization would drive this as that’s the point of localization. But then multilingual people use more than one keyboard and so with that context, yeah, at a button click they want to change localization as they type in different languages.